# How to specify the minor version of Microsoft.NetCore.App

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, web-config

I have a web app made in .NET Core 3.1, which uses the `Microsoft.NetCore.App` framework.

My csproj file looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <Win32Resource />
    <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
    <RunPostBuildEvent>OnOutputUpdated</RunPostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

When I run the app in my local machine, both are taking by default the version that I have installed: 3.1.**29**. I know this, because when I run the app I see its taking the dlls from this folder: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.29`

I assume its taking the latest version, by default.

The problem is, in the servers, I have 3.1.**28** installed. So when I run the app in the server I get this error:

> HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies Common
> solutions to this issue: The specified version of
> Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.

How can I force my app to run using the 3.1.28 version of this framework? I cannot update the framework in the server, because I got no permissions.

I tried with `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1.28</TargetFramework>`, but that won't work.

I also tried to specify the version in a global.json file, but it seems is not doing anything:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp3.1": {
      "version": "3.1.28"
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: This is what I got in the server, in case you are wondering if something is missing:

```
dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version: 6.0.400
Commit: 7771abd614

Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Windows
OS Version: 10.0.14393
OS Platform: Windows
RID: win10-x86
Base Path: D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\

global.json file:
Not found

Host:
Version: 6.0.8
Architecture: x86
Commit: 55fb7ef977

.NET SDKs installed:
1.1.14 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.526 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.109 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.118 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.420 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.421 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.422 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.406 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.408 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.301 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.302 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.400 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.14 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.14 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.27 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.28 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.15 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.7 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.16 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.13 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.14 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.27 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.28 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.15 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.7 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: That's not how this works, you don't need to specify the minor version. If any version of 3.1 exists on the server, it will be used. Are you 100% sure you installed the *hosting bundle* on the server though?

Comment: Also, what is in your web.config for this deployment?

Comment: @DavidG The hosting bundle is installed, because if I change from 3.1 to 2.0 it works fine. Is a version problem of some of the packages or frameworks. My app do not have a web.config, but a appsettings.json. I do know that version 3.1.28 of NetCore.App and AspNetCore.App are installed, because I see it in the logs:

`.NET runtimes installed:
...
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.28 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
...
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.18 [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]`

Comment: The hosting runtime is not the same thing as the SDK. Check [this page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) and see the link for the ASP.NET hosting bundle there.

Comment: @DavidG Check the log: ".NET runtimes installed", that's not the SDK. I do have the hosting bundle installed. Check at my comment, please. If I downgrade to any older version, it works. Also, you are sending me a link to .NET Core 6.0 and I'm working with 3.1. In any case, as I said in the question, I do not have permissions to install anything in the server.

Comment: @DavidG I have added the `dotnet --info` response so you can see what I have installed in the server.

Comment: `dotnet --info` doesn't tell you if the *hosting bundle* is installed. There are 3 components here. The SDK, the runtime and the hosting bundle. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efvh5.png

Comment: @DavidG Is hosting bundle necessary to run a .NET Core 2.1 application?

Comment: I think so, been a long time since I looked at 2.1 though.

Comment: @DavidG Then is installed. So that's not the problem.

Comment: But you may have an old version, I do know it has been updated since at least v3

Comment: publish your app with `self-contained` mode?